# Compatibility: will an application with Android 2.2 work on phones which have Android 2.0 or 2.1?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

I am using eclipse Hellios. My question is 
I am developing an application with Android 2.2, will it work on phones which have Android 2.0 or 2.1

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether you're using parts of the API which were added after Android 2.0 or 2.1. The best way of ensuring that you only use compatible APIs specify Android 2.0 ( API Level 5) as your build target. By doing this, you will get compile time errors if you try and use APIs which are not available in 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

It may have some problem if the ApI's u use are not present in the other versions like 2.1 and 2.0.. but vice versa is possible.. a android 2.1 application will work fine in 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you define as minSDKVersion on your Manifest... If the API Level is lower than that value it won't even install...But if you're not using the API's from higher versions, your best option is to always compile in 1.5 or 1.6